# python assign a variable to a randomly selected string

Tags: python

my children and I are messing with a random bedtime story generator. And apart from being amazed at how easy python is to use, we want to generate a random name for our protagonist, but for them to keep the same name throughout the story.

```
import random
names= ["Tim", "Ju Ju", "Legface", "Dusty", "Smudger"]
thing = ["princess", "elf", "fairy", "mermaid", "shoe maker"]

count = 0
while (count < 1):

  print "Once upon a time there was a ",
  print(random.choice(thing)),
  print "whose name was ",
  print(random.choice(names)),
```

so if the random name turns out to be Tim, I would like to continue the story as

```
print $thevariablethatisTim 
print "was a very happy man"
```

I realise this is a trivial thing, but I can't seem to get it right and we are having such a good laugh at bedtime with this.

Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: `name = random.choice(names)`?!

Comment: Well, you're using variables, and you're calling functions. Do you know how to assign the return value of a function call to a variable?

Comment: Do you need `if` statement to check whether you `random.choice` is `Tim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just choose the name of your hero before you enter the `while` loop.

```
hero = random.choice(names)
# stuff
while some_condition:
    # do stuff
    print(hero) # or formatted string
    # do other stuff
```

any time you want to refer to your protagonist, use the variable `hero` instead of calling `random.choice` again.